# Prolog - Confusion With Order of Printing in Recursion

Tags: prolog

Given the following program:

```
postIt([]).
postIt([c|R]) :- postIt(R), !, nl.
postIt([X|R]) :- postIt(R), write(X).
```

Query:

```
?- postIt([a,b,c,d,e]).
```

Trace:

```
    [trace]  ?- 
|    postIt([a,b,c,d,e]).
Call: (8) postIt([a, b, c, d, e]) ? creep
Call: (9) postIt([b, c, d, e]) ? creep
Call: (10) postIt([c, d, e]) ? creep
Call: (11) postIt([d, e]) ? creep
Call: (12) postIt([e]) ? creep
Call: (13) postIt([]) ? creep
Exit: (13) postIt([]) ? creep
Call: (13) write(e) ? creep
e
Exit: (13) write(e) ? creep
Exit: (12) postIt([e]) ? creep
Call: (12) write(d) ? creep
d
Exit: (12) write(d) ? creep
Exit: (11) postIt([d, e]) ? creep
Call: (11) nl ? creep

Exit: (11) nl ? creep
Exit: (10) postIt([c, d, e]) ? creep
Call: (10) write(b) ? creep
b
Exit: (10) write(b) ? creep
Exit: (9) postIt([b, c, d, e]) ? creep
Call: (9) write(a) ? creep
a
Exit: (9) write(a) ? creep
Exit: (8) postIt([a, b, c, d, e]) ? creep
true.
```

I don't quite understand why the output is 'ed'  'ba'. I figured that the program would print 'ab' skip 'c' then print 'de'. I am hoping someone may be able to clarify this for me.

Comment: Short answer: **Don't**!  Prolog can be best understood by focusing on what relations are described by its predicates (that's the "declarative" viewpoint.).  Performing side-effects and then try to reason about it plus tracing is a dead-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I address the actual question, one additional point: Please consider using `more_readable_names_with_underscores` `insteadOfStickingItAllTogetherLikeThis`. Thus, I suggest for example the name `post_it/1`.

Next, to make our life simpler, I will only consider the following **fragment** of your code:

```
post_it([]).
post_it([X|R]) :- post_it(R), write(X).
```

That is, I have simply *omitted* the second clause entirely.

What do you expect now from the query `?- post_it([a,b,c,d]).`? Is it `abcd`?

**No**, obviously it *isn't*:

```
?- post_it([a,b,c,d]).
dcba
```

**Why**? In your case, since you are using the **impure** predicate `write/1`, the reason for this can only be understood *procedurally*, that is taking into account the actual *execution strategy* of Prolog.

The execution strategy of Prolog is called, among other names, *depth first search with chronological backtracking*. When you have a clause like:

```
a :- b, c.
```

then, when `a/0` is executed, `b/0` is invoked **first**, and *only if `b/0` succeeds*, `c/0` is invoked.

Thus, consider for example the simpler query:

```
?- post_it([a,b]).
```

First, `post_it([b])` is invoked, and it emits `b` (**Exercise**: Why?). Only **then**, `a` is emitted, because `write(a)` occurs as the *second goal* in `post_it/1`.

Obviously, in such simple cases, we can still somehow grasp the procedural definition. The major deficit of this is that this quickly becomes *way too complex* to understand, and so I can only recommend to *avoid* side-effects: They will invariably make your code too hard to understand, and you are already seeing the first signs of this.

Recommendation: Work in the **pure** subset of Prolog. In your case, consider the following **relation** between lists:

```
without_c(Ls0, Ls) :-
        tfilter(dif(c), Ls0, Ls).
```

This uses `tfilter/3` from Ulrich Neumerkel's [**`library(reif)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) to declaratively describe the relation between two lists, where the second list is the same as the first, but without any occurrence of the atom `c`.

Example query:

```
?- without_c([a,b,c,d], Ls).
Ls = [a, b, d].
```

Much more general cases work too, for example:

```
?- length(Ls0, _), without_c(Ls0, Ls).
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = [c],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_7366],
dif(_7366, c) ;
Ls0 = [c, c],
Ls = [] .
```

Note that such relations can be easily **tested**, because the arguments can be reasoned about explicitly, much in contrast to *output* that only occurs on the terminal. In addition, this program admits a declarative reading, freeing you from many operational considerations.

Note also an additional problem of your original definition: Due to the usage of `!/0`, it has become extremely hard to predict the effect of removing the second clause. The resulting program is not more specific (as would be expected otherwise), but actually emits solutions that were previously not emitted!

Comment: Silly me. Makes perfect sense now, thank you for your thorough answer Mat

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend you simply avoid side-effects, and reason about all entities using predicate *arguments*. Only then will you be able to fully benefit from declarative approaches, because you will often be able to use your predicates in multiple directions, in addition to other benefits. Let the toplevel print the answers for you!